# "Required" HTML5 tag not working

Tags: html

```html
<form id="contact_form" action="/contact-verzenden" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input  class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="name" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Naam':this.value;" value="Jouw naam" required/>
    <input  class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="tel" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Telefoon':this.value;" value="Telefoon" required/>
    <input  class="textbox" type="text" name="email" id="email" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'E-mail':this.value;" value="E-mail" required/>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="30" type="text" name="message" id="message" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Vraag/opmerking':this.value;" required >Vraag/opmerking</textarea>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
</form>
```

When I click submit, the data sends regardless of whether something has been entered or not.

Even though it's exactly the same as the W3 schools example:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser are you testing this on...?

Comment: Every browser. I think it has something to do with the fact that I use set values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you still have **value** in every input elements.
Try using placeholder to make it look like your design.

```
<input  class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="test" required/>
```

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to remove your javascript event

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already giving him value (`value="Jouw naam"`) and also onblur you are giving it a value (`"Naam"`). So the value is **never** empty. That`s why it is submitting the form.

Add `placeholder="Jouw naam"` instead of `value = "Jouw naam"`

Hope it helps !!

Comment: It's cool, onblur didn't have to leave. all I had to do was replace "value" with "placeholder".

Comment: Yes you can use place holder instead of value

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form id="contact_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input  class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="name" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Naam':this.value;" placeholder="Jouw naam" required/>
    <input  class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="tel" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Telefoon':this.value;"  placeholder="Telefoon" required/>
    <input  class="textbox" type="text" name="email" id="email" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'E-mail':this.value;"  placeholder="E-mail" required/>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="30" type="text" name="message" id="message" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Vraag/opmerking':this.value;" required ></textarea>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
</form>
</html>
```